# Java Generics not working

Tags: java, generics

Why Generics not working in my machine. Why below code not working in Eclipse without Type casting to the `String`. I am using Java 1.6

```
package com.withgeneric;

 class Util {
    // Generic static method
    public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
        return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
               p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
    }
}

 class SPair<K, V> {

        private K key;
        private V value;

        // Generic constructor
        public SPair(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        // Generic methods
        public void setKey(K key) { this.key = key; }
        public void setValue(V value) { this.value = value; }
        public K getKey()   { return key; }
        public V getValue() { return value; }
    }



public class GenericMethod {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pair<Integer, String> p1 = new SPair<>(1, "apple"); //Giving Error
        Pair<Integer, String> p2 = new SPair<>(2, "pear"); //Giving Error
        boolean same = Util.<Integer, String>compare(p1, p2);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: What does _not working_ mean? I've never seen a compile or runtime error with this message.

Comment: What is working in your machine?

Comment: Hope you use the proper java.util.List library

Comment: Are you getting compile error in eclipse.

Comment: it is giving compile time error

Comment: It is giving error: Type Mismatch canot convert object to string.

Comment: Do you have other JDK's installed on the host ?

Comment: I have only one jdk installed i.e C:\Documents and Settings\rk53824>for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\javac.exe

Comment: It **does** work. See this [ideone snippet](http://ideone.com/Wl3p8q).

Comment: have you checked the JVM configured in your eclipse project? Go to configure build path and then check if the correct libraries are included

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler and look up JDK compliance. Make sure it's at least 1.5.

Comment: Compiler compliance level set to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

This works without cast since Java 1.5.

```
package java.util;

public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {

    ....        

    E get(int index);

    ....

}
```

Maybe useful: [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 0):

This statement can't give any error if you are using java 1.5 or greater. But if you are using some older version than

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

will give error. First you will have to solve this issue than type cast will come.

Comment: THat is th issue here Saurabh,My jdk compliancelevel is 1.6.Still i am getting error in compile time.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the JVM configured in your eclipse project? Go to configure build path and then check if the correct libraries are included

Answer (score 0):

Write an ENTIRE PROGRAM that has in it the lines you've posted above.  Do NOT copy-and-paste them, type them all in.  Include lines necessary for a java program, i.e. `public static void main (String[] args)` etc.  Do a 'clean' and 'build' on that program, and tell us the entire result.  If that's still causes an error, post the entire program and the entire error.

Also be aware that it is difficult (at best) to figure out what's wrong with another machine's configuration without being able to look at it; help us get information about what's there.  Abrupt answers make it appear that it is really Java you want us to fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't tell us what your error is, and this program does not contain the lines you had previously.  You aren't doing the same thing with String, so I assume you aren't required to cast to String.  I thought `new SPair<>(a,b)` was 1.7 syntax, and so I would expect an error in 1.6.  Hopefully we can converge to one set of code, one or a few errors from that code, and one or a few questions related to the two, and we will all know what they all are at the same time.