# Eclipse on Windows cannot resolve java.util.Comparator

Tags: java, eclipse, comparator

I'm not familiar with Java or Eclipse. There's a java program with several imports that I want to run. I created a new project in Eclipse and pasted in the code, but it draws a red line under java.util.Comparator and says it cannot be resolved. All other imports work.

Confused, I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse and overwrote the previous version, but problem still exists. I wrote a HelloWorld program and it works.

Here is a code sample to reproduce the problem:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator; // error: The import java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MyClass
{
    class MyComparator implements Comparator // error: Comparator cannot be resolved to a type
    {
        public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1)
        {
            ArrayList<String> ap0 = (ArrayList<String>) arg0;
            ArrayList<String> ap1 = (ArrayList<String>) arg1;
            return ap0.size() - ap1.size();
        }
    }

    void work()
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator()); // error: The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) from the type Collections refers to the missing type Comparator
    }
}
```

The compiler (or builder?) also says: 
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.util.Comparator. Fix the build path then try building this project

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing that your problem might be with generics, that your code has a `Comparator<T>` or something similar. If so then change the Java compiler "compliance level" setting to 1.5 or higher. For better help, show a small full program that does not work along with the complete error message. Let's avoid guessing.

Comment: For example, please check out the answers here:[Java Generics not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784591/java-generics-not-working)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels code sample added. Compliance level is 1.7.

Comment: I have no idea. What happens if you delete the specific import for Comparator, and then on your implements Comparator line, place the cursor at the end of `implements Comparator` and press ctrl-space (if you're on a Windows system) to let Eclipse automatically fill in the import?

Answer (score 2):

If you have both JRE7 and 1.8 installed, switch from 1.8 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line of java.util.Collections, then click ctrl+shift+o and choose the correct one.If it doesn't show the recommended items, the left of new red line will show you the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an old Java version for Eclipse start VM or have set up an older JVM for the workspace or project settings. The easiest thing to check is to check *JRE System Library* node in the project explorer and select properties to pick another one. You may need to install/register all installed/known JDKs under *Windows->Preference->Java->Installed JREs*. Eclipse compiler will inherit the source compliance level from the selected JRE.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have 2 JREs installed, one in 1.8.0_31 (came with Eclipse) and one in 1.8.0_45. Tried switching but neither works. Also, in project properties, the compiler compliance level is 1.7.