# Using jdk1.8 and recieving weird error

Tags: java

I have this code: `ArrayList<Integer> num_array = new Arraylist<Interger>();`

WHY am I getting this error: `"Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater"`

Comment: How do you compile this code?

Comment: Java generics were introduced with Java SE 5.0. You're using an older version. [This question also goes over solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784591/java-generics-not-working)

Comment: people still use 1.4? poor guys.

Comment: How can I fix this? Also how can I view my current version of Java?

Comment: You still didn't tell us how you compile your code...

Comment: Sorry, in Eclipse Indigo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "compiler compliance level" in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584427/what-is-compiler-compliance-level-in-eclipse)

Comment: You should move to newer version of Eclipse. From what I remember Indigo can't support Java 8. Earliest version which supported it was Kepler (but you need to download additional plugin). Java 8 is being supported from Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Luna is still a little problematic with lambdas, especially autocomplete inside lamdas seem broken. Mars does a much better job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your eclipse, go to the menu under `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler`. That will allow you to change the java version with the "Compiler compliance level" setting, since it appears to be set to `1.4` or lower.

EDIT: Also, if that does not work, right click on the project in the Project Explorer to the left of the screen, choose Properties and select `Java Compiler`. Apply the same changes here as well.

Comment: It was set to 1.4, I thank you sir. I am doing Java in school and we are expected to learn stuff on our own

Comment: @RobertTossly No problem! There's always a stage of figuring out where everything is in a new IDE.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure if you can answer this, but since I have changed my compiler to 1.7, I am still receiving the same errors. There was a notification about a total rebuild, do I need to create a new package perhaps?

Comment: @RobertTossly You can try either a) Going to `Project -> Clean...` and letting it clean all projects, and if that doesn't work, b) restart eclipse.

Comment: Sadly, I have cleaned AND restarted Eclipse and still am getting this error :-/ Thanks for answering the initial question though!! :-)

Comment: @RobertTossly I might have another solution. I'll edit the answer, one moment.

Comment: I owe my life to you sir. You want my car? You got it? Want a loan of my girlfriend? You got it! THANK YOU SO MUCH! My program is working fine now!! :'-)

Comment: @RobertTossly Haha, glad to help!